# Modify Inline Styling, Multi-Elements Deep

Tags: jquery, css, greasemonkey, inline-styles

I'm attempting to modify the coloring of a CometChat on a website which will remain anonymous due to having a non-modified CometChat. I just want to change the coloring, but prefer to use Greasemonkey over a User Styling extension due to not wanting to install a single extension for a single page.

I've changed the background color so that it is black, which is fine until I go to modify the default text color (Black), to be white.
The system appears to style text based on the color in a Cookie, but it uses an Inline Style on a span.

I can't figure out how to modify only the Inline Style where it is "color:#000000" (No, they don't have an appending ";") without changing all other colors, and removing a feature from the chat.

I tried:

- Using jQuery's `.attr` to find the value, then apply a class which has an `!important` color.
- Using `.attr` to change the color directly.

I Also tried `span[style="color:#000000"]` and a few other methods, nothing has worked so far.

One thing I noticed is that while trying to `alert()` to see if it's working at all (In some attempts during `.each`), it wouldn't create the alert. The only reason that I can think of is that it is several Div's deep into the document. (`html > body > div#container > div#currentroom > div#currentroom_left > div#currentroom_convo > div#currentroom_convotext > div > div.cometchat_chatboxmessage > span.cometchat_chatboxmessagecontent > span` (The one I wish to Edit) )

Comment: Oh i should probs mention, The entire chat is dynamically generated through JQuery and PHP for Cometchat :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that that/those span(s) is/are added by AJAX (Can't tell from the question).  Whether they are or not, you can use `waitForKeyElements()` to change it/them:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

waitForKeyElements (
    "#currentroom_convotext div.cometchat_chatboxmessage > span.cometchat_chatboxmessagecontent > span", 
    changeChatMessageCSS
);

function changeChatMessageCSS (jNode) {
    jNode.css ("color", "white");
}
```

---

Indicate whether the page resets the inline styles or uses `!important` in its CSS. (It probably does not do either.)

Comment: Trying the solution now, i've got it in a new user script, but it appears that it isn't work? (No elements are changing).

Also, It doesn't reset any information previously sent, however it does re-build the entire page when refreshed

Comment: Okay, looks like i got it working, I just had to understand a few concepts (Like what jNode was (I'm a complete idiot when it comes to javascript XD) and how to properly use it!). My solution was `if ( jNode.attr ('style') == 'color:#000000' ) { jNode.css ('color', 'red'); }` Thanks a lot for the help!! (And the edit :>)